# R can't read random columns of my CSV file

Tags: r

R thinks that the columns "nonrow" (which I added as a tester) and "sample" don't exist (it says they're null) in the following CSV file. (It sees every other column fine...)

```
nonrow,,Fill Weight,Fill Weight,Fill Weight,Fill Weight,xbar,r,sample
0,,352,348,350,351,350.25,3,1
0,,351,352,351,350,351,2,2
0,,351,346,342,350,347.25,8,3
0,,349,353,352,352,351.5,1.5,4
0,,351,350,351,351,350.75,1,5
0,,353,351,346,346,349,5,6
0,,348,344,350,347,347.25,6,7
0,,350,349,351,346,349,5,8
0,,344,345,346,349,346,4,9
0,,349,350,352,352,350.75,2,10
0,,353,352,354,356,353.75,4,11
0,,348,353,346,351,349.5,7,12
0,,352,350,351,348,350.25,3,13
0,,356,351,349,352,352,3,14
0,,353,348,351,350,350.5,3,15
0,,353,354,350,352,352.25,4,16
0,,351,348,347,348,348.5,1.5,17
0,,353,352,346,352,350.75,6,18
0,,346,348,347,349,347.5,2,19
0,,351,348,347,346,348,2,20
0,,348,352,351,352,350.75,1.25,21
0,,356,351,350,350,351.75,1.75,22
0,,352,348,347,349,349,2,23
0,,348,353,351,352,351,2,24
```

I have tried moving the column around, renaming it, and trying the tester column (which it also mysteriously can't see). Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the .csv file? It will be easier to help you then.

Comment: pleasehelpmeout, I can load this data without any options, so if you are having problems then it is due to your code. Please provide the code and specific errors/warnings you are receiving.

Comment: @r2evans -  How are you loading the data. I would like to do the same, but can't make it work. Could it be a regional problem?

Comment: @r2evans I imported the file into R using fillweights <- read.csv('file location/filename.csv', header = TRUE). print(fillweights$xbar) does what it should and prints every number in that column, but print(fillweights$sample) prints NULL. I also can't find the average, max, min, etc. of that column, while I can do those things with the xbar column... for whatever reason it's effectively invisible to R.

Comment: pleasehelpmeout, that type of information is critical to asking the question. Furthermore, comments can often become hidden in questions, while that information is important to stand-out. Please edit the original question and put that code in there. While you're at it, you can read about how to [format code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), to make it easier for readers to quickly scan and see relevant information.

Comment: But given the sample data you've provided and confirming the code (as I tried before), I cannot reproduce your NULL problem.